# Adding two three-word numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, emu8086

This is what I have done so far:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 64 
.DATA
X DW 5463h,0F8A8h,0D37Eh
Y DW 87DEh,3408h,92C2h
Result DW 3 DUP(0) ;Trying to add X, Y with the result being here.

.Code
MAIN PROC FAR 
MOV AX,@Data
MOV DS,AX 

;Adding X,Y:
;Getting Pointers Ready
LEA SI,X
LEA DI,Y
LEA BP,Result
MOV CX,3 ; Counter
CLC ;Clearing the carry
PushF ;We don't want the flag to be affected from the next two operations
;Looping three times to Add Word by Word 
WordAdd:
MOV AX,[SI+4] ;We will iterate from the least significant word (4) to the most significant word (0)
MOV BX,[DI+4]
PopF ;Retaining the flag register
ADC AX,BX
PushF
MOV [BP+4],AX
Sub BP,2
Sub SI,2
Sub DI,2
Loop WordAdd

MOV Ax,[BP]
MOV BX,[BP+2]
MOV CX,[BP+4]

MAIN ENDP 
END MAIN
```

For some reason AX, BX, CX are all 0000 in the end, but I cannot figure out why, even though I made sure that addition is performed correctly and put in AX each time through debugging.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but on the last iteration of your loop, the `pushf` never gets popped.

Comment: Thank you for noting this out, I added one pop after the loop :)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code correctly computes the sum and stores it at the three words at `Result`, in your unusual mixed-endian order.  However, keep an eye on the address in `BP`: you start it pointing to `Result` and decrement it by 2 on each iteration of the loop.  Since you store words in your loop to `[BP+4]` you get the correct ones, but after the loop `BP` points to `Result-6`.  So your loads into `AX, BX, CX` are taken from `Result-6`, `Result-4`, `Result-2` respectively, which are not where the sum was stored.

Some more general suggestions:

- Your current design needs all sorts of magic offsets like `[BP+4]`, `[BP+6]`, etc, scattered throughout the code.  These all depend on your array size, so you're effectively hardcoding that size in about 10 places.  Think of the pain when you want to modify your program to add four-word numbers instead, or heaven forbid, a length to be determined at runtime.  So you might think about designs that would avoid that.  For instance, if you started with `BP` pointing to the last element instead of the first.
- As Brendan says, your mixed-endian word order is unconventional and would likely confuse other programmers.  Reversing the order would also simplify your code in that you could go through your arrays forward instead of backward.
- A sequence like `MOV BX,[DI+4]` / `ADC AX,BX` is redundant when you can simply do `ADC AX, [DI+4]`.  The CPU designers went to a lot of trouble to make every instruction usable with one memory operand; might as well take advantage.
- `LEA SI, X` could be replaced by `MOV SI, OFFSET X` which does the same thing but uses one byte less.  The same for your other `LEA`s that just load a constant address.
- Remember that memory references using `BP` are implicitly relative to the stack segment `SS`.  That's fine for a `SMALL` model where `DS` and `SS` are equal, but should you switch code models, you'll wonder why your code is not writing to `Result` even though `BP` "obviously" points to it.
- You are using four different registers in your loop (`BP, SI, DI, CX`) which are all basically just keeping track of the loop index.  See if you can get this down to one.  You can have a single register used as an offset into all the arrays by doing something like `MOV AX, [X+BX]` `MOV DX, [Y+BX]`.
- The `LOOP` instruction is a bad habit if you're eventually going to move to working with modern x86 CPUs, as it's poorly optimized and its use is discouraged.  Doing the decrement and conditional jump yourself is actually more efficient on such machines, and it also gives you the freedom to use any register instead of being tied to `CX`.
- Likewise, the `PUSHF/POPF` trick is also a bad habit, as these instructions are quite expensive on modern CPUs since they potentially manipulate the interrupt flag.  Try to design the rest of your loop so that it leaves the carry flag intact between iterations.  The `INC` and `DEC` instructions are nice here because they don't modify it; loops like this are exactly why they were designed that way.
- Capitalize your mnemonics and register names consistently.  Some people like all caps, some people like all lower case, but nobody likes mixed case.

Answer (score 2):

There's at least 2 bugs:

a) The last `pushf` never gets popped (as mentioned by Nate Eldredge in comments). This will probably cause the program to crash when returning to its caller.

b) You've got the order around the wrong way. 80x86 is little-endian, and you're doing the "most significant word first". This will make the carries wrong (if it was decimal digits instead of 16-bit words, it'd be like "090 + 010 = 001").

Note that because you know there will always be 3 words, and because 3 is small, it's better to do it without any loop. This might look like:

```
MOV AX,[X]
MOV BX,[X+2]
MOV CX,[X+4]
ADD AX,[Y]
ADC BX,[Y+2]
ADC CX,[Y+4]
```

Also note that all modern 80x86 CPUs (since 80386 from 1985) allow you to use 32-bit instructions in 16-bit code. This allows you to do something more like:

```
MOV EAX,[X]
MOV BX,[X+4]
ADD EAX,[Y]
ADC BX,[Y+4]
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain what do you mean with that I'm doing "the most significant word first" I tried to sidestep this problem by doing: 

MOV AX,[SI+4] ; We will iterate from the least significant word (4) to the most significant word (0)  (Same for DI, BP)

Comment: @Essam: "little endian" means that the least significant part goes in the lowest memory address; so a 48-bit value like `0x123456789ABC` would be stored in memory as the bytes `0xBC, 0x9A, 0x78, 0x56, 0x34, 0x12`; or as the 16-bit words `0x9ABC, 0x5678, 0x1234`. To get the carries right, you need to do "lowest address to highest address" (but your loop is doing "highest address to lowest address").

Comment: I know about the little-endian thing, but I thought it would be true only within each word of the three but not also for the three words as a whole. Now I got the idea.
so I should start from [SI+0],[DI+0],[BP+0] and increment by 2 instead of decrementing, correct?

Comment: I think my original idea of little-endian is the one correct, when I ran your code I got Ax=DC41 BX=2CB0 CX=6641 However, starting from [X+4], [Y+4] instead yielded the correct answer.

Comment: @Essam: If you treat everything as little-endian you will get the right answer. If you treat everything as big-endian (have the original data wrong, do the calculation wrong, then treat the result wrong) then you will also get the right answer. The problem is that as soon as you try to improve the code (e.g. use 32-bit instructions) you'll quickly find that using big-endian was a huge disaster. It'll also confuse everyone else (because everyone else will expect little-endian).

Comment: @Essam: Note that "big endian" isn't technically correct. What you're actually using is "mixed endian" - e.g. the value 0x123456789ABC would be stored as the bytes "0x34, 0x12, 0x78, 0x56, 0xBC, 0x9A" (little endian within each word, and big endian for the 3 words).